# CoinMP Solver on LibreOffice Calc not available

Tags: libreoffice

I am running LibreOffice 6.4.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (the version that comes preinstalled by default) and I noticed that it does not have the CoinMP Solver. When I open the Solver Options, I only have two options:

- LibreOffice Linear Solver
- LibreOffice Swarm Non-Linear Solver

There is no CoinMP solver, which is the default solver on LibreOffice Calc. Why is it not enabled on Ubuntu?

I asked this question on Ask LibreOffice and I was told that CoinMP is still the default solver on LO and they were surprised that it was not shipped with Ubuntu 20.04.

Is it possible to enable CoinMP yet? Do I need to install another package? Or will I have to reinstall LibreOffice?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed in the libreoffice changelog (in Linux Mint, but it looks like this is also the Ubuntu version):

```
libreoffice (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo3) focal; urgency=medium

* Backport from hirsute
* Enable CoinMP support
```

See [https://launchpadlibrarian.net/529778243/libreoffice_7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1~lo3_source.changes](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/529778243/libreoffice_7.1.2%7Erc2-0ubuntu0.20.04.1%7Elo3_source.changes) and [https://launchpadlibrarian.net/529912485/libreoffice_7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.20.10.1~lo3_source.changes](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/529912485/libreoffice_7.1.2%7Erc2-0ubuntu0.20.10.1%7Elo3_source.changes)